# Wordpress coming soon page and production code together

Tags: wordpress, virtualhost

I am quite new to Wordpress so not sure if this is possible or not. I have a domain and a coming soon page(index.php). 
When I go to `domain.com` I can see coming soon page which is fine. Now I am planning to update the same directory with Wordpress code but will be invisible to the outer world until I make some final changes.
For example, can I access the Wordpress site in this way -

`domain.com/index1.php`

Once the changes are done I can rename the index1 to index and the site can be public.

Apache virtual host conf file looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias www.domain.com

     <Directory /var/www/domain.com/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd develop the website on a separate subdomain/subfolder (eg. `dev.my-domain.com` or `my-domain.com/dev`), then move everything into the public folder (and adjust the URL in the database as well) once the website is ready for deployment.

Comment: ... or you could install any of the various Maintenance Page plugins that are around, use that as your "coming soon" page, and develop your website directly in the public folder without worries then disable said plugin once the site is ready for the general public.

Comment: @cabrerahector Thank you. I think it would be better to have a separate subdomain or subfolder.